# ImageIcon does not display image when passed with a string parameter

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

When I set up the panel with the filename written in for the ImageIcon it works fine:

```
public TitlePanel(){
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout( this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ));

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/q0.png");
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel( image);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150,40)));
    add(imageLabel);
}
```

However when I pass the ImageIcon a string, it stops working with no error message. The image just does not come up, but it prints out the right string path:

```
public static String imageName = "\"images/q0.png\"";

public TitlePanel(){
    setOpaque(false);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout( this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ));

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imageName);
    System.out.println(imageName);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel( image);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150,40)));
    add(imageLabel);

}
```

The file hierarchy is as follows:

1. projectName

   - src

     - TitlePanel
   - images

Does anyone know why this would cause ImageIcon to not be able to find the file?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String imageName = "\"images/q0.png\"";
```

Quotes should not be part of the filename.

The code should be:

```
public static String imageName = "images/q0.png";
```

This is not just for filenames, it is for any variable. You don't include the quotes as part of the string.